# Sync Outlook calendar with color categories to Android tablet

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, android, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

I'm setting up all my appointments in Outlook using categories with their accompanying colors. How can I sync my Outlook calendar to my Android tablet in a way that my colored categories will be preserved? I prefer a wireless solution.

Comment: What kind of e-mail account are you using in Outlook?

Comment: My local ISP's mail (Telenet).

Comment: Does this mean in Outlook you're accessing your ISP e-mail account via IMAP or POP3?

Comment: Acessing via IMAP

Answer (score 2):

I've not done this myself but **[CompanionLink for Outlook](http://www.companionlink.com/products/outlook.html)** claims to support this feature. According to the [product description](http://www.companionlink.com/products/outlook-categories.html):

> CompanionLink for Outlook, combined with the free DejaOffice app for Android and Apple devices, allows users to map Outlook Categories to their devices. This process not only preserves existing Outlook categories, but the colors you've assigned to each category as well.

The product supports a number of sync connectivity [options](http://www.companionlink.com/products/outlook.html) including Wi-Fi, USB, and the vendor's cloud-based solution called "DejaCloud".  Be aware of two caveats of syncing Outlook categories:

> Syncing via Google does not fully support Outlook categories. Direct USB Sync is not available for syncing Outlook Categories to Apple devices.

Android installation guides [here](http://www.companionlink.com/support/kb/Android_Setup_Guides).  iPhone installation guides [here](http://www.companionlink.com/support/kb/Apple_Setup_Guides).

This is a commercial product. They currently offer a one-time license cost of $49.95 or a 3-month subscription for $14.95.  There's also a 14 day [trial](http://www.companionlink.com/downloads/download.php?product=CLO70).

*<sup>Note: I'm not affiliated with this product/vendor in any way.</sup>*